# Softball C++ question: How to compare two arrays for equality?

Tags: c++, arrays, equals

I am trying to compare two int arrays, element by element, to check for equality.  I can't seem to get this to work.  Basic pointer resources also welcome.  Thank you!

```
int *ints;
ints = new int[10];

bool arrayEqual(const Object& obj)
{
    bool eql = true;

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        if(*ints[i] != obj.ints[i])
            eql = false;
    }

    return eql;
}
```

Comment: dereferencing arbitrary pointer types seems suspect to me.

Comment: Instead of having a eql variable, why not replace "eql = false;" by "return false;" and "return eql;" by "return true;"? The behavior should be the same and the function faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `if(*ints[i] != obj.ints[i])`, what you are comparing is the address pointed by `ints[i]` with the content of `obj.ints[i]`, instead of the content of `ints[i]` itself. That is because the name of an array is already a pointer to the first element of an array, and when you add the subscript, you will look for the ith position after the first in that array. That's why you don't need the `*`.

The correct is:

```
int *ints;
ints = new int[10];

bool arrayEqual(const Object& obj)
{
    bool eql = true;

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        if(ints[i] != obj.ints[i])
                eql = false;
    }

    return eql;
}
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 15):

how about the following?

```
#inlcude <algorithm>

bool arrayEqual(const Object& obj)
{
   return std::equal(ints,ints + 10, obj.ints);
}
```

Note: the equal function requires both arrays to be of equal size.

Comment: Counternote: It just requires the latter range to have _at least_ as many as the first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody's asked why you're using arrays in the first place. While there are places that arrays can be hard to avoid, they're few and far between. Most of your code will normally be simpler using std::vector instead. Since std::vector overloads operator==, all you have to do in this case is something like `if (a==b) ...` Even in the few places that vector isn't suitable, TR1::array will often do the job (and IIRC, it provides an overload of operator== as well).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is all wrapped by "class Object {" and "}"?

Just remove the "*" and it should work.